# Can't get result from three EditText's?

Tags: java, android, integer, textview, android-edittext

I am trying to take numbers from three EditText boxes that the user fills in, then through some simple math and the user pressing a button, there needs to be an answer through a textView. Also whenever I launch this app on the emulator it says that it needs to Force close once I click on the button to go to this layout and code. Here is the code:

```
                 package com.app.one;

import com.app.one.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class monthlyp extends Activity {
int x = 10;
int y= 10;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.monthlyp);

      final TextView input = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editone);           
      final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equals);
      final EditText textView13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView13); 

      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            y = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
            textView13.setText(String.valueOf(y));
        }
      });       
}
    }
```

I know it only has one EditText area but that's because I need help adding two more and being able to use them as integers to add/subtract/divide/multiply. The xml has all three edittext boxes and an equals button that will solve what is entered. Thanks for the help and please ask me if you need any more information.

Comment: Can you provide the Logcat for your error?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't have any errors when I save and launch it. It just crashes on this screen/files. What would be the code needed to add two more EditTexts while still having the one equals button to combine all the EditTexts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that input is a textview

```
final TextView input = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editone);
```

then you got the integer value of that textview

```
y = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

I suggest that's not what you intended

Comment: Yeah, I switched those around, now how would I add more text boxes and have each one convert what is entered into an integer or maybe a string which ever is best for calculating then releasing a final answer to the user, probably in the form of a textView but i'm not sure. thanks so much

Comment: In your layout you can define more edittext boxes, then in your on click button you can use as you're trying to do the data from all of those boxes to do the calculations

Comment: Should I do it like this:                                            final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editone);            final EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittwo);                 Then what code would I use to then take what is entered then do like editone x edittwo or whatever after the equals button is pressed?

Comment: You have the right idea with y = ... blah blah
now get y2 from edittext 2 and say x = y* y2; and set that as the textview text

Answer (score 2):

First off it appears that your input is a TextView and your output is an EditText. This seems backwards. If your XML is correct and your input is an EditText you may have problems trying to cast it as a TextView.

Comment: Ok I switched them around but I'm not sure how to then add more EditText's but still have them all connected to the one button so it can solve what is entered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two things right away:

1. You converted the string to an integer, and then back to an integer again to put it in the other field. This is bad, it's called yo-yo code. Save the string value and store that, instead.
2. Integer.parseInt() can throw a NumberFormatException if you don't put a valid integer in that EditText. You need to try/catch around it for that exception and handle the invalid cases, preferably by calling setError() on your edit text.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

edit: and yes, like the others said.. don't name your EditText "textView13"

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be getting your input from the TextView and posting the output to the EditText.  Shouldn't that be the other way around?

Comment: Ah... @Pyrondante beat me to it.